# This vhdl code doesn`t do what I want . What do I do wrong?

Tags: project, vhdl, implementation, fpga

I am working at a school project and I have to design a machine that sells tickets. There are many requirements and I took care of many of them but I have a small problem. Me, the designer decides what is the initial number of tickets in the machine. And then, after the clients buy one ticket at a time this number should decrease with one unit. It does not. What is wrong? (I am a beginner when it comes to writing code in VHDL).

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity bilete is
   port(en1,en2: in std_logic;
    init: in std_logic;
    B: out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0); 
    err: out std_logic;
    ok: out std_logic);
end bilete;

architecture Bil of bilete is
   signal en : std_logic;
   constant C: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0):=x"0002";
   signal M: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);

begin
en<= en1 nor en2;
P: process(en,init,M)

variable Verr: std_logic:='0';
variable Vok: std_logic:='0';
variable K: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0):=x"0000";

begin

    if init='0' then      -- inititialize the number of tickets
        K:=C;
        M<=K;
      if en='0' then
        Verr:='0';
        B<=K;
        Vok:='0';
    else if K<0 then 
        Vok:='0';
        B<=x"0000";
        Verr:='1';
    else if K>0 then
        Verr:='0';
        Vok:='1';
        B<=K-x"0001";
        K:=K-x"0001";
        M<=K;
    end if;
    end if;
    end if;


    else  if init='1' then  -- decrement

     if en='0' then
        Verr:='0';
        B<=M;
        Vok:='0';
    else if M<0 then 
        Vok:='0';
        B<=x"0000";
        M<=x"0000";
        Verr:='1';
    else if M>0 then
        Verr:='0';
        Vok:='1';
        B<=M-x"0001";
        M<=M-x"0001";
    end if;
    end if;
    end if;

    end if;
    end if;
err<=Verr;
ok<=Vok;
end process P;
end Bil;
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the conditional syntax should be `elsif` instead of `else if`? And why do you have so many `end if`?

Comment: It can be both. I have an end if for every if statement. The main problem  is that i do not know how to update the number of tickets(initialised with a certain value ) after tickets are sold one by one.

Comment: First: please format and indent your code, either use correct indentation or elsif statements. Secondly, your design has no clock. Using short identifier names does make the design faster or smaller, it just hinders us to understand your code ... my last note: Don't do arithmetic calculations on std_logic_vector, use the type signed or unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

K is a signal with no assignment when `init='1'`. This creates an implicit latch rather than a flip-flop.

Comment: I know that is one of the problems but I do not know how to write code in order update the number of tickets after one was sold.

Comment: You have implicit latches in your nested `if-elseif` statements that are not matched by `else`. So you also have an implicit latch on your output port, `B`. Its not surprising that your output is not as expected. You really need to fix this before trying to debug your code.

Comment: There are no flip flops in the code. It's hard to find FFs without a clock signal.

Comment: If nothing is synchronous with a clock, then everything is a latch?